# How to run docker image in AKS without using docker repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am using Azure Kubernetes Service(**AKS**) and I am no allowed to use Docker Hub repository for pushing and pulling Images, so please tell me, is there a way to create **kubernetes deployments or pods** by using tar of image or by pulling image using **ssh connection** from other server in which I am having Docker engine running.

Comment: How about using [Azure Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/)?

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about Azure Container Registery, will this work as same as docker hub in docker commands? How can I configure my AKS to pull images from Azure Container Registery.
Thanks in advance @NguyenLamPhuc

Comment: Yes, it is pretty much the same that you can login with username/password and are ready to push and pull from there. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration) for details instructions on how to connect your AKS and ACR.

Comment: @NguyenLamPhuc can you post it as an answer? It will be more visible to community when posted as an answer and others can benefit from it.

Comment: Except for the ACR, you can also use a private registry. You can install it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the reason why you are not allowed to use Docker Hub is because of the company policy that wants to keep everything private and contained within Azure.

In that case, I suggest using the Azure's own container registry service named [Azure Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/) which have the following benefit:

- It works similar to DockerHub in the sense that you can just sign in with username and password, update the image name and you are good to go.
- It is the solution from Azure which should fit nicely in your Infrastructure design. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration) for details instructions on how to connect your AKS and ACR.
- The traffic flow from AKS and ACR is private and not exposed to the Internet.